# How do I pass SYSDATE or USER (oracle key words) as IN parameters to a mybatis stored procedure call in mapper xml?

Tags: mybatis

I have Pojo containing all the IN parameters and out paraeters , but some of my stored procedure IN parameters expect me to send USER (oracle keyword) and SYSDATE as IN parameters. How can I user my POJO objects In parameters and the Oracle key word in parameters together in the Stored procedure call using mybatis mapper xml?
I am using mybatis with Spring 3.

Comment: I think I am able to figure out myself. We just give them as SYSDATE and USER , you do not need to give the mode of parameter whether in or not.

Answer (score -1):

insert into OBJECT  values(#{id}, sysdate)

Comment: As I said I got the answer already. and this answer does not seem to be addressing stored procedure call in My batis.. this is more of a regular query.